# Thingsboard Delete/Remove/Disable Rule Chain

Tags: iot, thingsboard

I want to remove a Rule Chain that I no longer need, how I do that?

The option is disabled, I believe because it is in "Root", but I also didn't find an option to remove it from "Root" (clicking on the checkbox only opens the properties window, as if I had clicked anywhere on the row, it does not change the status) and simply deleting the nodes of the chain is not a option, as I notice that it is still being triggered by the forwarded messages.

I looked everywhere and couldn't find any instructions.

Note: I am using Thingsboard Cloud v3.4.1PAAS ("Maker" in trial mode)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's mandatory to have exactly one Root Rulechain. Therefore it cannot be deleted. Click on the Flag icon of another Rulechain to mark it as the new Root Rulechain. Afterwards you should be able to delete the first one.

Please keep in mind that the Root Rulechain is responsible for receiving all the incoming data. If your Root Rulechain has e.g. no Rulenodes for saving the data, your data will be lost.

https://thingsboard.io/docs/pe/user-guide/rule-engine-2-0/overview/

> Tenant administrator is able to define one Root Rule Chain and
> optionally multiple other rule chains. Root rule chain handles all
> incoming messages and may forward them to other rule chains for
> additional processing. Other rule chains may also forward messages to
> different rule chains.